How to assign default prop values with Svelte 5 and TypeScript?
Suppose I have the following Svelte 5 component:
<script lang="ts">
  const props: {
    name: string;
    age?: number;
  } = $props();
</script>

<div>Name: {props.name}</div>
<div>Age: {props.age}</div>

I want props.age to have the default value of 40.
How can I do that, while keeping the props. prefix to access the values?

I found that, as of December 2024, there is no standard way to to this.
I opened an issue at Svelte repo, and I will update this answer if the Svelte team publishes something.

Referring to the docs:
Fallback values
Destructuring allows us to declare fallback values, which are used if the parent component does not set a given prop:
let { adjective = 'happy' } = $props();
Type safety
You can add type safety to your components by annotating your props, as you would with any other variable declaration. In TypeScript that might look like this...
<script lang="ts">let { adjective }: { adjective: string } = $props();</script>
Putting it together:
<script lang="ts">
  const {
    name,
    age = 40
  } : { name:string; age?:number } = $props();
</script>

<div>Name: {name}</div>
<div>Age: {age}</div>

Edit:
keeping .props:
type Props = { name:string; age?:number }
let props : Props = $props();
const dafault: Partial<Props> = {age:40}

props = Object.assign({}, dafault, props)


Your example uses destructuring of the prop variables (that is: without the props. prefix). How can I do it keeping the props. prefix?

@rodrigocfd only if you do props.age ?? 40

or by manipulating the object. just edited with that

No dude, this is an ugly hack. Since there's no standard way to solve this, I opened an issue at Svelte repo.

One way is to define a class and set values to the properties of that class on initialization.
A second/simple way is to have a defaultValues object which you can copy from.
For examples const defautObj = { age: 40 }; let props = { ...defaultObj };
